# How are these duplicates?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145359/which-revision-control-system-to-use-for-2-semester-capstone-course/145368#comment274842_145368) was closed as a duplicate, but I'm not seeing it.  One's asking us to consider issues for a college group project for people who have little to no experience with version control.  The [alleged duplicate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69308/git-for-personal-one-man-projects-overkill) is an experienced version control user wondering whether to switch to something more powerful for one-man non-academic projects.  Even though both questions fall into the broad category of "version control," the evaluation criteria are completely different, and therefore the "why" and "how" explanations are going to be different.

It wouldn't surprise me if the question has been asked before, but the [linked duplicate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69308/git-for-personal-one-man-projects-overkill) isn't it.

Comment: would you mind if it gets "re-closed" as [not constructive](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/are-getting-started-with-questions-constructive "Are “Getting started with…” questions constructive?")? I was just considering to cast such a vote when it got closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be my slip up.

The question had three close votes.

One as a duplicate of the question you linked to, the other two as "not constructive".

I saw the question took a quick look at the duplicate and thought that it was probably a duplicate. However, looking at it now I see that it's not really.

However, I would have closed as not constructive, so I'm going to go ahead and and reopen and reclose with the correct close reason.

Comment: It still felt like there was a good question in there somewhere.  Would an edit along the lines of "what factors are most consequential in this situation" make it constructive?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt "most sequential" feels quite slippery. ["How do I tell which VCS <insert the purpose here>?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/165773 "guidance on asking and answering best / recommendation type questions") - probably less so

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you.

They do seem like altogether different questions to me, however the original question still seems terribly Not Constructive.  It is basically inviting a bunch of answers with peoples opinions on their favorite source control with high general metrics:

> easy to use (ie this should be a tool they can use rather than spend a lot of time fighting it)
>
> Easy to install and maintain for the person who does this.
>
> still be relevant for subsequent professional work once they graduate

These are desirable traits in a good laptop let alone source control software.

The question should still be closed in my opinion but I just feel the reason listed is wrong.

**EDIT:** ChrisF posted his response before me, this answer is now defunct!